# Where can I find the maps folder within StarcraftII?

Tags: directory, reinforcement-learning, starcraftgym

I am trying to set up Starcraft II for Deep Reinforcement Learning, following this [Tutorial](https://github.com/deepmind/pysc2).

At some point I am adviced to download the maps:

> **Get the maps**
>
> PySC2 has many maps pre-configured, but they need to be downloaded
>   into the SC2 Maps directory before they can be played.
>
> Download the ladder maps and the mini games and extract them to your
>   StarcraftII/Maps/ directory.

Thing is I am not able to locate my Maps directory.
Any advice or hints are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Create one yourself

So the thing is, I could not find it, since there is none.
The easy solution in hindsight is to create one:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\StarCraft II\Maps\mini_games
```

*Hint:* Make sure to not put your maps directly into the Maps folder but within another subfolder (e.g. mini_games), otherwise the maps won't be found.